# How to place a letter in the corner of the subplot including axis labels (not the corner of the axis)

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, transform, subplot

I want to label subplots with letters in the upper left corner (A, B, C, ...) that are either aligned to the ylabels or to the actual corner of the subplot (not the axis).

If the subplots are of different width, I can't use text with an offset in axis transform coordinates anymore, as that would result in different distances for each subplot. So I use an offset transform usually. But this doesn't work anymore if the ylabels have different widths. I also currently eyeball the offset for each plot but this is not good enough.

This is what I have so far:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 3, width_ratios=[1, 2, 3])
axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i]) for i in range(3)]

ylabels = ["flat label", "bigger\nlabel", "even\nbigger\nlabel"]
labels = ["A", "B", "C"]

scaledtrans = transforms.ScaledTranslation(-0.4, 0, fig.dpi_scale_trans)

for ax, ylabel, label in zip(axes, ylabels, labels):
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.text(0, 1, label, fontsize=12, fontweight="bold", va="bottom", ha="left",
           transform=ax.transAxes + scaledtrans)
```

As you can see in the image below, the labels are the same distance from the axis spines, but I want them aligned to the left edge of the ylabels or the corner of the subplots, which in this case would coincide horizontally with the ylabels. There is no transSubplot though, only transAxes and transFigure

[image]

Comment: Any subplot is an axes. So the notions are a bit hard to understand here.

Comment: I think the OP wants the labels at the edge of the gridspec, rather than relative to the axes.  Unfortunately, that's hard to get a-priori (constrained_layout does positioning at draw time).  My approach would be to trigger a draw, get the position of the ylabels and place the text in figure co-oridinates that way.  You can also get the axes bounding box determined by constrained_layout by looking at `ax._layoutbox`.  Obviously thats private, so don't complain if it changes ;-)

Comment: yes that's correct, I tried to determine the position of the corners of the layoutbox but these seem to contain the theoretical variables, not the solved ones in figure coordinates. How would you go about retrieving the y-label position in figure coordinates then?

Comment: `get_window_extent` should do it...

Comment: I tried `axes[0].yaxis.get_label().get_position()` but it returns `(21.736577777777796, 0.5)` and that's not in figure coordinates. The transform of the label seems to be a blended affine transform, but I don't know how to get from that to figure coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the idea is to place the label at the edge of the tight bounding box of the respective axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 3, width_ratios=[1, 2, 3])
axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i]) for i in range(3)]

ylabels = ["flat label", "bigger\nlabel", "even\nbigger\nlabel"]
labels = ["A", "B", "C"]

for ax, ylabel in zip(axes, ylabels):
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)

fig.canvas.draw()

for ax, label in zip(axes, labels):
    bbox = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
    fig.text(bbox.x0, bbox.y1, label, fontsize=12, fontweight="bold", va="top", ha="left",
             transform=None)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The obvious drawback of this is that one cannot change the figure size afterwards. A little bit better might be to transform back to figure coordinates first, and also use a callback on draw events to update the coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 3, width_ratios=[1, 2, 3])
axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i]) for i in range(3)]

ylabels = ["flat label", "bigger\nlabel", "even\nbigger\nlabel"]
labels = ["A", "B", "C"]

for ax, ylabel in zip(axes, ylabels):
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)

fig.canvas.draw()

axlabels = [fig.text(0,0, label, fontsize=12, fontweight="bold", va="top", ha="left")
            for ax, label in zip(axes, labels)]

def update_labels(evt=None):
    trans = fig.transFigure.inverted()
    for ax, label in zip(axes, axlabels):
        bbox = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
        label.set_position(trans.transform_point([bbox.x0, bbox.y1]))

update_labels()
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("draw_event", update_labels)

plt.show()
```

Note that one key element here is that `fig.text` does not take part in the constrained_layout mechanism. So such solutions will only work for positions that are within the figure boundaries.

Comment: The first one is great for static images; the second doesn't work on high-dpi monitors unfortunately.  I don't know of an easy way to make the label track the edge of the layout box under resizing.  You *could* make an axes to put the label in and then make an axes locator that looks up the edge of the layout box at draw time.  That seems like a lot of work for something I'm not convinced is generally desirable; most times the subplot label is either in the upper left of the axes itself or in the title of the axes.

Comment: @JodyKlymak One could use a callback on draw events to reposition the labels though. Maybe you can test if the updated second solution now works on "high-dpi" devices as well?

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty much what I wanted :) I didn't know about tightbbox and calling draw before adding more elements in display coordinates, so this was all very helpful. I usually create pixel perfect plots for publications with fixed dimensions like this so I never need to think about what happens when resizing.